# How to create masterKey after MasterKeys deprecated in Android

Tags: kotlin, encrypted-shared-preference

I am using the following code to store some information encrypted in my app.

```
    val masterKey = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC)

    val sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        "secret_shared_prefs",
        masterKey,
        this,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
    )
```

Since the MasterKeys class deprecated in Android, I should use the MasterKey class and but I cannot figure out what is the right method to get the same mastery defined.

Could somebody show the exact match with the available MasterKey and MasterKey.Builder classes?

The below solution worked like this:

```
val spec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        "_androidx_security_master_key_",
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
    )
        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
        .setKeySize(256)
        .build()

    val masterKey: MasterKey = MasterKey.Builder(this)
        .setKeyGenParameterSpec(spec)
        .build()

    val sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        this,
        "secret_shared_prefs",
        masterKey, // masterKey created above
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM);
```

Comment: Hey, instead of using the hard coded Maste key alias and key size of 256, you should use 
`MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS` and `MasterKey.DEFAULT_AES_GCM_MASTER_KEY_SIZE`

Comment: EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(...) is also deprecated

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem today. See below for fix/workaround (example is in Java code but you can easily do the same in Kotlin)

1. Use MasterKey.Builder to create MasterKey (instead of MasterKeys). Build it with "manually" created KeyGenParameterSpec:

   ```
    // this is equivalent to using deprecated MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC
    KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            MASTER_KEY_ALIAS,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .setKeySize(KEY_SIZE)
            .build();

    MasterKey masterKey = new MasterKey.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setKeyGenParameterSpec(spec)
            .build();
   ```
2. Create EncryptedSharedPreferences using slightly different version of "create" method:

   ```
    EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
            MainActivity.this,
            "your-app-preferences-name",
            masterKey, // masterKey created above
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM);
   ```

That should do the trick :)

Reference and more details: https://devmainapps.blogspot.com/2020/06/android-masterkeys-deprecated-how-to.html

Comment: Thanks, Sir! I was close, but the documentations are not really clear for this. :) I have added the code in my question.

Comment: This is great, thanks. how can you return an existing Master Key?

Comment: this requires min API 23

Comment: Where is `KEY_SIZE` ?

Comment: @xproph for ```MASTER_KEY_ALIAS``` and ```KEY_SIZE```, Can we use ```DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS``` and  ```DEFAULT_AES_GCM_MASTER_KEY_SIZE```

Comment: MasterKey is not found !!!

Comment: what is `MASTER_KEY_ALIAS` no one tells that! Does it have to be the alias for App's Keystore file or just any random name?

Answer (score 54):

try this one

```
MasterKey masterKey = new MasterKey.Builder(context, MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS)
        .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
        .build();

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        context,
        SHARED_PREF_NAME,
        masterKey,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM);
```

Comment: Why do I see a warning in the logs of "keyset not found, will generate a new one" ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper developer Got any solution for this warning?

Comment: @Ameer I think it is ok to ignore those warnings.

Comment: I implement this solution but getting this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68825081/androidx-security-crypto-encrypted-prefs-key-keyset-does-not-exist
Can you please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 15):

My version to get secret shared preference :

```
private fun getSecretSharedPref(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
    val masterKey = MasterKey.Builder(context)
            .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
            .build()

    return EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(context,
            "secret_shared_prefs",
            masterKey,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
    )
}
```

Comment: Perfect good :)

Answer (score 11):

you can use either of the way

```
KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
     MASTER_KEY_ALIAS,
     KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
     .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
     .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
     .setKeySize(KEY_SIZE)
     .build();

MasterKey masterKey = new MasterKey.Builder(MainActivity.this)
     .setKeyGenParameterSpec(spec)
     .build();
```

or

```
MasterKey masterKey = new 
              MasterKey.Builder(context,MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS).
              setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM).build();
```

MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM internally use same key generatespec as stated above.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it like this below

```
//Creating MasterKey
            val masterKey = MasterKey.Builder(context)
                .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
                .build()

            val fileToRead = "your_file_name.txt"
            val encryptedFile = EncryptedFile.Builder(context,
                File(context.filesDir, fileToRead),
                masterKey,
                EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
            ).build()
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version based on responses here with dependency on [Security kotlin version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security) `androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx`

```kotlin
class EncryptedPrefsImpl(context: Context) { 
    private companion object {    
        const val PREFERENCES_NAME = "some_file_name_here"
    }

    private val spec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
    ).apply {
        setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
        setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
        setKeySize(MasterKey.DEFAULT_AES_GCM_MASTER_KEY_SIZE)
    }.build()

    private val masterKey = MasterKey.Builder(context).apply {
        setKeyGenParameterSpec(spec)
    }.build()

    val preferences: SharedPreferences by lazy {
        EncryptedSharedPreferences(
            context,
            PREFERENCES_NAME,
            masterKey
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, something new. First time saw someone just for example at least mentioned `MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `-ktx` version of `androidx.security:security-crypto` you can reduce some of the boilerplate to just this:

```
val encryptedSharedPrefs = EncryptedSharedPreferences(
    context,
    ENCRYPTED_STORAGE_FILENAME,
    MasterKey(context)
)
```