# Creating MasterKey causes UserNotAuthenticated even when authenticationrequired is false

Tags: java, android, security, kotlin

While reviewing some code I noticed that MasterKeys was deprecated in androids newest crypto library. I changed my code around following [This stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498977/how-to-create-masterkey-after-masterkeys-deprecated-in-android) It works fine on every device I have tried EXCEPT for my Pixel4XL on Android 11 Beta (RPB1.200504.020).

I wrote a separate class for getting the masterkey so that it could be accessed from two different activities. Here:

```
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
import androidx.security.crypto.MasterKey;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

public class GetMKey {

public MasterKey getmkeym(Context context) {
    KeyGenParameterSpec spec = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                .setUnlockedDeviceRequired(true)
                .setIsStrongBoxBacked(true)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .setKeySize(256)
                .build();
    } else {
        spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .setKeySize(256)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                .build();
    }

    try {
        MasterKey masterKey = new MasterKey.Builder(context)
                .setKeyGenParameterSpec(spec)
                .build();

        return masterKey;
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I then use this (in Kotlin) with:

```
var mk = GetMkey()
val sharedprefernces = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(this, "ENCRYPTEDSHAREDPREF", mk.getmkeym(this), EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV, EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM)
```

On the Android studio emulators P3a API29 and P3a API30 as well as my GalaxyS10+(API28) it runs perfectly fine. However on my Pixel 4XL running the android 11 beta it throws a "User not authenticated" error: **EDIT NOTE: After further investigation, it appears that on the pixel it works after the phone is unlocked for around 10 seconds. Tried turning on authenticationrequired and setting authenticationvalidityduration to a higher amount but to no avail. Still throws error only on this device**

```
2020-07-03 21:08:03.018 27585-27585/REDACTED E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: REDACTED, PID: 27585
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
 Caused by: android.security.keystore.UserNotAuthenticatedException: User not authenticated
    at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1346)
    at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1388)
    at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
    at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.encrypt(AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.java:64)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.KeysetHandle.encrypt(KeysetHandle.java:180)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.KeysetHandle.write(KeysetHandle.java:157)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager.write(AndroidKeysetManager.java:385)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager.readOrGenerateNewKeyset(AndroidKeysetManager.java:350)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager.<init>(AndroidKeysetManager.java:133)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager.<init>(AndroidKeysetManager.java:96)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.build(AndroidKeysetManager.java:208)
    at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:153)
    at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:119)
    at REDACTED.LoginActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(LoginActivity.kt:54)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7438)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7415)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28286)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
```

Not sure if this is a problem with the beta or if I have implemented it incorrectly. Any help would be much appreciated and I would be happy to provide more info if needed. Thanks!

Comment: It is a beta, I'm wondering if this Q/A site is the best place for this question. Not that it is bad or anything, but maybe a more Android specific site is better?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yeah I'm just a teenage developer trying to learn more about security and android haha. Thought this would be a good place to ask. I do believe it is an issue with the beta specifically and not the device. Got my hands on a P4XL with Android 10 and it worked just fine. Any idea where I could go to report this issue?