# How to save password in sharedpreference?

Tags: android, passwords, sharedpreferences

I have done login and registration activity using rest API. But in login I used only Mobile number editext. And in registration I used password. So I want to use that password in login. Means user should enter that password while he used during registraton.
So how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to store passwords, make sure you store them in `EncryptedSharedPreferences`. You do not have to encrypt them manually as the library will take care of it.

If you need/want more explanation on this and how it works, check out some articles about it on the web - there are plenty.

Answer (score -1):

If your using Kotlin, saving password in Shared Preferences could look like this:

Initialize Shared Preferences:

```
var prefs: SharedPreferences
prefs = getSharedPreferences("name_of_your_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Save password to it:

```
with (prefs.edit()) {
    putString("password", etPasword.text)
    apply()
}
```

If you want to access this stored password, you can do it like this:

```
val password = prefs.getString("password", "default_value")
```

Comment: Actually I'm using java

Comment: Always store the credentials as hashes. Here I found implementation of [SHA256](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55920601/6773266). You can create your own hash function too. 

Also I would highly recommend to use encrypted share preferences to store the credentials. I found a good example [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62144168/how-to-implement-encrypted-sharepreferences).